# How to read sar file from different ubuntu system

Tags: logging, syslog

I am using two different version on ubuntu one is 14.04 and other is 15.10. I want to read 14.04 systems sar files from ubuntu 15.10 system. I have transferred the sar files but can't read it.

Comment: What is the exact way you are trying to read them and what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I am using the command # sar -pd -f sa08

and the error is:
Invalid system activity file: sa08
File created by sar/sadc from sysstat version 10.2.0
Current sysstat version cannot read the format of this file (0x2171)

Comment: I am using SYSSTAT version 11.1.5. I know its different version but I want know is there any way to make it happen with different version of SYSSTAT.

Answer (score 2):

`sadf` has `-c` argument which is:

```
   -c     Convert an old system activity binary datafile (version 9.1.6 and later) to 
          current up-to-date format. Use the following syntax:

          sadf -c old_datafile > new_datafile
```

In my case I wanted to use recent (systtat >= 11.3.1) SVG plotting feature of `sadf` and it complained with:

```
Current sysstat version cannot read the format of this file (0x2171)
```

Running `sadf -c old > new` (sysstat 11.6) did the trick.

I used this to plot all the data in `saNN` file into SVG:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/tmp/data -w /tmp/data alpine:3 \
  sh -c "apk add -q --update sysstat 2> /dev/null && \
         sadf -c saNN > /tmp/sa 2> /dev/null && \
         sadf -O packed -g /tmp/sa -- -A" > saNN.svg
```

Also see sysstat's [portability of sa data files](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/135) issue.

Answer (score 1):

Different version of sar files are not necessarily compatible and I think the file format changed between those versions you have. You can either downgrade sar on your system or try to install the exact version you have on the older system. If you just need the information you can dump out it to text version on the older box .

See one example from SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348914/output-sar-command-results-to-a-csv-file